# Configuración de servidor DHCP en firewall

Tags: redes, firewall

Tengo un firewall WatchGuard, cuya configuración ya estaba hecha por personal anterior. El problema, si se le puede llamar así, es que me percate que la interfaz interna tiene una configuración que no me cuadra, tiene una IP estatica 192.168.1.254 con una mascara de red 255.255.252.0, tengo entendido que esa mascara de red es de clase B, sin embargo, la ip 192.168.1.254 es de clase C ya que clase B solo llega hasta el 191 y tiene un servidor DHCP configurado de 192.168.3.15 a 254 y me tiene confundido el hecho de que el firewall aceptara la configuración y a parte este funcionando. Varios usuarios me han reportado que tienen problemas para conectarse en ocasiones incluso por cable, es posible que esto sea el origen del problema?. No soy un experto en redes y esto me hace sentir que todo lo que sé esta mal.
Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

(Más vale tarde que nunca)

El concepto de redes IP con clases A, B o C ha sido «mejorado» (por decirlo así) hace ya tiempo, permitiendo un uso más eficiente de las direcciones IP. [Más información](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Una red con máscara `255.255.252.0` (como se dice ahora, máscara /22) es válida, y equivale a decir que la red local tiene en caso direcciones que van desde 192.168.0.1 a 192.168.3.254.

Si la máscara de red nofuera homogénea, puede que algunos nodos tuviesen problemas para llegar a otros, pero no creo que sea la razón de los problemas de conexión, ya que el servidor DHCP con esa configuración le indicará la máscara correcta a cada cliente.

Comment: una red con máscara 255.255.255.252 creo que es prefijo /28

Comment: Si, tienes razón. De todas formas [Luis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/24390/luis-felipe-gonz%c3%a1lez) habla de una red `255.255.252.0` (que es /22) y yo transcribí mal en la respuesta. Gracias por notarlo!